# supporting notifications for both Windows Phone 8 and 8.1

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-8, push-notification, windows-phone-8.1

I am creating new windows phone application from scratch and I would like to support both WP8 and WP8.1. I started project as Blank WP Silverlight app and it's okay. I get emulators for both WP8 and WP8.1. I want now implement notifications. So here goes my questions:

- If I upgrade this project to WP8.1 could it be compatible with WP8? When I send it to Store will it be available for both versions?
- If I want support both versions and use notifications I must use MPNS for notifications? Because WNS is available only for WP8.1 projects right?
- Should I split solution to multiple projects and share code files between them? Something like to have WP8 project and WP8.1 project and some project for sharing code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Q** : **If I upgrade this project to WP8.1 could it be compatible with WP8? When I send it to Store will it be available for both versions?**

**ANS** : If you upgrade your project from WP8 to WP8.1 and published to store then it will not available for Windows Phone 8 devices. It is only capable in which have Windows Phone 8.1.

**Q : If I want support both versions and use notifications I must use MPNS for notifications? Because WNS is available only for WP8.1 projects right?**

**Ans :** If you want to support both the version then yes you must use MPNS for notification. In Windows Phone 8.1 Support both MPNS and WNS.

For more details for please refer these links [What's next for Windows Phone 8 developers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn655121(v=vs.105).aspx) and [Upgrade Windows Phone 8 apps to Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn642081(v=vs.105).aspx)

**Q : Should I split solution to multiple projects and share code files between them? Something like to have WP8 project and WP8.1 project and some project for sharing code.**

**Ans :** Yes you can Share your code to multiple project. Just create **Windows Phone Class Library** for your common code  and make it dll and use in your project.